# How to navigate back to a Login ViewController after signing out from Google Sign In

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, uiviewcontroller

I'm implementing Google Auth for the first time and I'm running into some trouble when I attempt to Sign Out from my root viewController in my navigation stack. I'm trying to transition back to the login View Controller, which is located outside of my navigation stack, but I'm not too sure how to implement that, and I'm doing everything programmatically, so no storyboards.

This is my Sign Out function in my root View Controller, as you can see I'm pushing the viewController to the login screen, which isn't correct since a push only adds the viewController to the stack, whereas I need it to transition back to a View Controller that is outside of the navigation stack.

```
//MARK: - Sign Out Button
    @objc func signOut(){
         let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
        do {
          try firebaseAuth.signOut()
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.disconnect()
            
            let loginVC = MainViewController()
            navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true) //This should not be a push VC...
            
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
          print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
    }
```

Comment: if its outside the navigationStack .... you need to push it again ...

Comment: Or set that Navigation Controller as root controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you sign out you shouldn't be pushing another `UIViewController` into the Navigational stack instead take the user to the `LoginViewController` which in your case seems to be named as `MainViewController` which is a bit confusing. You can set rootViewController once the logout is successful. Since you're doing everything programmatically this is what you should do in your `signOut` function.

```
@objc func signOut() {
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
    do {
        try firebaseAuth.signOut()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.disconnect()

        let loginVC = MainViewController()
        if let rootViewController = view.window?.rootViewController { // From iOS 13
            rootViewController = loginVC
        } else if let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController {
            rootViewController = loginVC
        }

    } catch {
        print ("Error signing out: %@", error)
    }
}
```

Additional Note: Also, don't need to cast the error in the catch block if you're not doing anything with it, the error is natively available for use.